# confusion about inputing an array in the main method

Tags: java, arrays, program-entry-point

I have this method that checks how many 9's are in an array.

```
 public static int arrayCount9(int[] nums){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i]==9) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I am getting an error on my main method and I don't understand why.

```
    public static void main(String [] args){

    System.out.println(arrayCount9([1,5,9]));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you create an array in Java. You have to use [array initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6). And you can use it here with an [Array Creation Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10):

```
System.out.println(arrayCount9(new int[] {1,5,9}));
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to initialize an int array and then pass that array in your method. Check this modified code :**

```
public static int arrayCount9(int[] nums){
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i< nums.length; i++){
            if(nums[i]==9) count++;
        }
        return count;
    } 
        public static void main(String [] args){

            int[] intArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        System.out.println(arrayCount9(intArray));
    }
```